# Ember does not detect Node update

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli, nvm

I'm running an Ember project on an Ubuntu 14.04.

Whenever I run commands like `sudo ember update`, I get this error message :

```
Future versions of Ember CLI will not support v0.10.25.
Please update to Node 0.12 or io.js.
```

So I upgraded node to 0.12.6 using nvm.

`node -v` gives : `v0.12.6`

`nvm ls` gives :

```
-> v0.12.6
system
```

Is there something wrong with the "system" node? Or a cache I should refresh in Ember?

Comment: Most likely the root user is picking up the older copy of node still. What does `sudo node -v` show?

Comment: `v0.12.6` Great this is it. How would you fix it from there?

Comment: I would suggest reinstalling node without sudo following one of [these techniques](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814)